# Convert for-loop using "mutate" function from dyplr package

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I need to convert the following for-loop using the `mutate` function from dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

rendimientosSpain <- 1

for(i in 1:length(data$PX_LAST_TEF_SPAIN)-1) {
  rendimientosSpain[i] <- log(data$PX_LAST_TEF_SPAIN[i+1] / data$PX_LAST_TEF_SPAIN[i])
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>%
  mutate(rendimentosSpain = log(lead(PX_LAST_TEF_SPAIN) / PX_LAST_TEF_SPAIN)
```